# Resizing text with keyboard shortcuts in Mathematica 10

Tags: version-10, keyboard

In Mathematica 10, it seems that the Alt+= and Alt+- shortcuts affect the entire cell instead of only the selected text. In the following example, I highlighted "line 2" and pressed Alt+= several times. The result is shown for Mathematica 9 on the left and Mathematica 10 on the right.

[image: font comparison]

I also ran into a strange situation in Mathematica 10 where the keyboard shortcuts changed the size of the entire cell *except* the selected text, but I wasn't able to reproduce this behavior. When I change text size from the Format menu, everything works as expected (i.e., only the selected text is affected). It's just the keyboard shortcuts that are acting strangely. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Can't duplicate the behavior you report with V10.0.1 running on OS X. The keyboard shortcuts work as expected.

Comment: Thanks for checking. I'm running v10.0.0.0 on Windows 7.